# WebView inconsistently showing white screen react-native

Tags: react-native, webview

I'm using a WebView to show an iframe of a twitch-stream in my react-native app, however at some points when it renders the WebView only shows up as a blank white screen until you scroll/move the UI and at other times it works as intended.
There are no errors emitted when the WebView is blank, it seems to load as intended so not really  sure why it just shows a blank white screen.

Here is the WebView code:

```
 <Animated.View
   style={{
     height: anim,
     width: width,
     overflow: 'hidden',
   }}
 >
   <WebView
     onLoadEnd={() => {
       useAnimation()
     }}
     source={{
       uri: `https://host.com/iframe/?channel=${channelName}`,
     }}
     style={{
       height: heightByRatio,
       width: width,
       flex: 0,
     }}
     mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}
     allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true}
   />
</Animated.View>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue of webviews sometimes loading blank on android devices. I can't say I figured out *why* it was happening, but I solved it by delaying the load of the webview and putting a 2px border around the container wrapping the webview. Neither solution worked on its own, both were needed.

```js
export default class WebviewExample extends Component<Props> {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
        
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({loadWebview: true});
        });
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.view}>
                {this.state.loadWebview && 
                    <WebView />
                }
               
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    
    view: {
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: 'transparent',
    }

});
```